# Tampermonkey - Cannot get data with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, tampermonkey

I am trying to get some data with Tampermonkey using JavaScript. The problem is with the regex, i designed it in RegExr (Air app) and it seems to work fine on the input text:

```
<div class="yt-lockup clearfix  yt-lockup-video yt-lockup-grid vve-check" data-context-item-id="Rg2PUqmNWe4" data-visibility-tracking="abc">
  <div class="yt-lockup-dismissable">
      <div class="yt-lockup-thumbnail">
  <span class=" spf-link  ux-thumb-wrap contains-addto"><a href="/watch?v=Rg2PUqmNWe4" class="yt-uix-sessionlink" aria-hidden="true" data-sessionlink="videos">  <span class="video-thumb  yt-thumb yt-thumb-196">
<span class="yt-thumb-default">
```

However in the code it does not show an alert:

```
var lis = document.getElementById("data").getElementsByTagName("li");
//alert(lis.length);

var item = lis[0].innerHTML;
alert( item.match( /(?<=data-context-item-id=").*?(?=")/g ) );
```

How can i return the string "Rg2PUqmNWe4"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is good solution for this problem:

```js
const data = `<div class="yt-lockup clearfix  yt-lockup-video yt-lockup-grid vve-check" data-context-item-id="Rg2PUqmNWe4" data-visibility-tracking="abc">
  <div class="yt-lockup-dismissable">
      <div data-context-item-id="this is also found" class="yt-lockup-thumbnail">
  <span class=" spf-link  ux-thumb-wrap contains-addto"><a href="/watch?v=Rg2PUqmNWe4" class="yt-uix-sessionlink" aria-hidden="true" data-sessionlink="videos">  <span class="video-thumb  yt-thumb yt-thumb-196">
<span class="yt-thumb-default">`

const getData = data => data.match(/data-context-item-id="(.*?)"/g).map(x => x.match(/"(.*?)"/)[1])

console.log(getData(data))
```

**step 1**
`data-context-item-id="` find this part.
**step 2**
`(.*?)` capture anything until `"`
**step 3**
`map` all found answers to get only data without atribute name

The advantage of this solution is the possibility of more than one occurrence of attribute as I shown in example.

Comment: @zeddex I'm happy to hear so :D

Answer (score 1):

Javascript regex engine doesn't support *lookbehind assertions* `(?<=...)`.
Use the following approach:

```
alert(item.match(/data-context-item-id="([^"]+)"/)[1]);
```

`([^"]+)` - matches all characters except `"`